# Error when attempting to end() SerialBT connection

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, esp8266, esp32

I'm working in a project with involves SPIFFS, Bluetooth and WiFi (Google Firebase). Since ESP32 can't handle multiple connections with one antenna I have to make them work in parts. I firstly make a connection with Bluetooth, get the data the user sends and store it into variables and into SPIFFS, the I should disconnect or end the Bluetooth connection and create the WiFi connection. But when I run .end(). I get the following error:

```
/home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/freertos/queue.c:1442 (xQueueGenericReceive)- assert failed!
abort() was called at PC 0x4008e57d on core 0

Backtrace: 0x400921a0:0x3ffd9080 0x400923d1:0x3ffd90a0 0x4008e57d:0x3ffd90c0 0x4016a3f9:0x3ffd9100 0x40172eb5:0x3ffd9120 0x401730bf:0x3ffd9140 0x4016a8e1:0x3ffd9160 0x4008e8e9:0x3ffd9190

Rebooting...
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
load:0x40078000,len:8896
load:0x40080400,len:5816
entry 0x400806ac
```

I initialize Bluetooth.begin() in the setup, than inside the loop I call a function that will run once, which ends the bluetooth, starts wifi and connects to datase.

Comment: Your steps to debugging the problem should be obvious. Open the mentioned file `queue.c`, go to the mentioned line 1442 and see what triggered the assert failure. Then work back from it. Other people may not have the exact same version of FreeRTOS code to check on your behalf.

Comment: esp32 can handle both bluetooth and wifi simultaneously - It works ok in my ESP-IDF based project

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is voltage too LOW, try to use 5V -> VIN.